# Check if date is less than a year ago MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field stored in the database logging when a user registered. For certain features they can only use them if they registered less than a year before. Is this possible to search via a single query?

Comment: How do you store the dates into the database? Timestamps or full dates?

Comment: From the perspective where you have preloaded all the data for a single user, you should simply compare the recorded register date in the session with the current date. There is no need for a SQL query, and especially not for one that returns all users that qualify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where registration_date > curdate() - interval 1 year
```

Comment: This query will return everyone that registered less than a year ago.  You can add `AND user=NNNNN` to return just the user's row if registration was less than a year ago.